# python-imaging and libjpeg on FreeBSD

Tags: images, python, freebsd, upload, django

I had a problem with image uploading to Django with FreeBSD, so I asked on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959447/django-uploading-image-error and got an answer.

Our admin can't install these libraries, he don't know how. Neither do I. It's FreeBSD, kinda unfamiliar system.

So, how do we install PIL with JPEG support and whatever needed for image uploading?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.e-shell.org/35) is an article about installation of `python-imaging` **port** (FreeBSD software package). `libjpeg` will probably be installed automatically as a dependency, but if it is not, you will just need to do similar actions to install `graphics/jpeg` port.